# ENV variables in scss file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, environment-variables

I would like to set the color of the navbar and jumbotron pic using environmental variables.

In my application.yml file I have

```
NAVBAR_COLOR: "#FF7F50"    
JUMBOTRON_PIC: 'asset-url("somePic.png")'
```

I have changed the custom.css.scss to custom.css.scss.erb and added the following lines

```
.navbar-default {
    background-color: <%= ENV["NAVBAR_COLOR"] %> ; 
}

.jumbotron{
  background-image: <%= ENV["JUMBOTRON_PIC"] %> ;
}
```

however, neither of the above works.

Any idea why?

Comment: I think it works, but CSS does not interpret strings as colors so `.navbar-default { background-color: '#FF7F50' }` does not work. Neither does the asset-url that is passed as a string and does nothing.

Comment: I tried NAVBAR_COLOR: red and still does not work. Looks like ENV variables are not updated instantly?

Comment: ENV variables are evaluated once on server start. If you changed a variable in the env, you need to restart the server.

Answer (score 1):

`.scss` files are not `.erb` files, so `<%= .... %>` won't work. Add an extra .erb extension to it and be sure it's precompiled server side and not locally and it will work only once at the moment of precompiling it.

Personally I wouldn't do this that way. For this I would just render that inside my template:

```
#layouts/mylayout.html.erb

...
<head>
  <style>
    .navbar-default {
      background-color: <%= ENV["NAVBAR_COLOR"] %> ; 
    }
    .jumbotron{
      background-image: <%= ENV["JUMBOTRON_PIC"] %> ;
    }
  </style>
</head>
...
```

Assets gets precompiled once and then delivered respond fast, it's not a good idea to make them depend on env variables and even worse idea if you plan to update that variable after precompiling it.

Comment: How can I refer to somePic.png which is located in app/assets/images? asset-url("somePic.png") will not work and I have tried url("app/assets/images/somePic.png") which does not work either...

Comment: I'm really not sure if I understand the use case. If the image is part of your rails project then you have to check the path generated when compiling it (something like /assets/somePic-38...89.png) and set that path as a variable. and do `background-image: url(<%= ENV["JUMBOTRON-PIC"] %>` but why not doing that without en ENV and using just the helper? if the image is only on the server but not a part of rails code, then you have to put it inside `/public` on each deploy and set the url for that. Really, I'd suggest yo improve the way you ask things, `will not work` can mean a lot of things.

Comment: Does not work means it does not load the image :). I know I can just use the helper (this is what I was doing so far) but there is a reason I want to do it with ENV variables.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the updating of ENV variables you have to restart the server as indicated in one of the comments.

For the background image to load correctly, I found that the following works:

```
#config/application.yml
JUMBOTRON_PIC: "/assets/somePic.png"
NAVBAR_COLOR: "#1ac2ff"

#layouts/mylayout.html.erb
 <style>          
   .jumbotron{
        background-image:  url( "<%= ENV["JUMBOTRON_PIC"] %>" );
      }      

   .navbar-default {
        background-color: <%= ENV["NAVBAR_COLOR"] %> ; 
  }  
 </style>
```